# how to invalidate form field in jquery plugin validate-engine to restrict it to submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I have an add lead form in which I am using validation engine plugin.

```
jquery_Lower_1_7_2("#formCustomer").validationEngine('attach', {promptPosition: "topRight", scroll: false});
if (jquery_Lower_1_7_2('#formCustomer').validationEngine('validate')) {
 // then add to database
}
```

There is an email field. When user lost focus from this filled after filling email, I call a function to check if email already used or not, if user then I show an error message using validate-engine plugin

```
jquery_Lower_1_7_2('#txtPrimaryEmail').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'Email is not available', 'error', true);
```

and if unique then

```
jquery_Lower_1_7_2("#txtPrimaryEmail").validationEngine('hide');
```

But if user click on submit button then it consider the form as validate and process with duplicate field, but I want to make it invalidate if email is not unique. How can I do this ?

Comment: along with the blur event, do the same check on submit also.

Comment: yes, I can do that. But is there any way to make form invalidate ?

Comment: what you mean by `form invalidate`?

Comment: Submit perform its functionality if form is validated 
if (jquery_Lower_1_7_2('#formCustomer').validationEngine('validate')) {
 // then add to database
}

if form in not validated then it will not add

Comment: Hello Sunil, did you find a solution to your answer?. I have posted a same question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969852/how-to-specify-custom-invalid-condition-in-jquery-validation-engine

Your question on github brought me here..
Please solve my question if you know the answer....